# 2 Letter Country Code via APEX

Tags: apex

I want to write an Apex method that takes a country name as input and returns the equivalent two letter country code (ISO A2). Is there a way to write it without explicitly hard coding all countries and code in the method? Can you walk me through how to do this from APEX? To clarify, I am trying to create a **custom field** on the account level with this return.

Comment: If you do not feel the duplicate answers your question, please **[edit]** your post to clarify. Then the community can vote to *reopen*. Asking the same question you have already isn't going to make things better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code from the following link: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000212327&type=1

Country Code:

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = User.Countrycode.getDescribe();
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
System.debug('Picklist::'+ple);
for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple){
System.debug(f.getLabel() +'::'+ f.getValue());
}
```

State Code:

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = User.statecode.getDescribe();
List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
System.debug('Picklist::'+ple);
for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple){
System.debug(f.getLabel() +'::'+ f.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Can you include details of the article in your answer? Just in case that article ever got removed or for some reason was inaccessible.

Comment: Thank you. Can you walk me through where in the dev console this should be coded?

Comment: I also just edited my post. I am trying to use this query to create a custom field. Is it possible?